# How to Encrypt AJAX GET & POST with javaScript and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, public-key-encryption, private-key

I would like to encrypt ajax post and get request with javascript.

The flow should be -

1. Server generated private and public key on request
2. Server sends the public key to client
3. Client encrypts the data with public key
4. Sever decrypts the data with the private key

I know SSL is an option, but my application is a small plugin which can be installed on any website that allows a user to purchase products on that website. Is there a way i can encrypt all the data at front end and decrypt at back end.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, in browser cryptography can be considered a [bad idea](http://matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/). Sending the data over ssl-tls would likely be much more secure than a home-brewed crypto solution, like you seem to be suggesting. This can be considered especially bad when transmitting data like credit card info, as it appears you will be.

http allows for extremely easy man in the middle attacks to eavesdrop on any data being sent either way, so there would almost certainly be no secure way to transmit the keys in the first place, let alone the secure information.

If you really *really* want to go this route, then have a look at [crypto-js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/).

This is not a good idea, and you should use SSL. Probably hence the downvotes.

Considering your use case, the best way to do this would probably be to host your own central service with SSL enabled, and route all ajax requests to your service, not theirs. Their servers could then poll your server using your SSL certificate, to view any relevant information. So you would be acting as some sort of centralised API, with both the clients and businesses connecting. You still need to consider however, that any information sent in the clear, ie over http, not https, can be tampered with before it reaches the user.

As far as I am aware, no, you cannot generate SSL certificates on the fly.

Comment: How do i install SSL for the domain that i don't own. What if the client that uses the plugin has no ssl feature installed. Is there a way where i can implement SSL certificate on the fly?